# Convert back to HTML entities from Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi there i have following line of code:

```
$('#chooseCurrencyType').append("<li>"+key+" - &#"+parseInt(data[key], 16)+"</li>");
```

It displays as below in html: `USD - $`

Here  `parseInt("0024", 16) = 36` and &#36 will display $(dollar) symbol....

So on executing below code...

```
($('.dropdown-toggle').text())  gives me $..
```

But how  to get the value `0024` from javascript  Or How to convert it back into html entity....

I tried like this:

```
($('.dropdown-toggle').text()).substring(6,7).charCodeAt(0);  gives me 36 ....
```

So how to convert 36 to 0024  ........ any help please....

Comment: You might want to look up String.charCodeAt

Comment: Hi there... i was bit confused when i was asking the question... so i made an edit.... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to convert character back to hex value? It doesn't really related to HTML entities.

Anyway, code for that would be:

```
function CharToHex(s) {
    var ascii = s.charCodeAt(0);
    return "0x" + Number(ascii).toString(16)
}
```

Usage:

```
var hex = CharToHex("$");
alert(hex + "\n" + parseInt(hex, 16));
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/cDAzm/).

Answer (score 0):

First off, why not just use `&#x20AC;`? That aside, to get it back you could try `JSON.stringify` and then match against `/\\u([0-9a-f]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use charCodes? It is more easy to convert. For example:

```
var n=String.fromCharCode(1255); // ӧ
alert(n);
n = n.charCodeAt(0); // 1255
alert(n);
```

Here is a complete list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters